# How do I copy text to clipboard in Avalonia?

Tags: clipboard, avalonia

I am trying to introduce a command which would copy the value of a bindable property to the system clipboard.

The only piece of information I could find is a very humble [Avalonia clipboard manual](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/input/clipboard) suggesting doing it this way:

```
await Application.Current.Clipboard.SetTextAsync("Hello World!");
```

But trying to do so causes an error:

```
Error CS0103 The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context
```

I have tried to resolving this by importing

using Avalonia;

Which made `Application.Current` visible yet it doesn't appear to include `Clipboard`:

```
Error CS1061 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Clipboard' and no accessible extension method 'Clipboard' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I guess accessing the clipboard might be meant to be done in the view rather than the viewmodel but the above problem appears the same even if I try the same in the view code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the 0.10.x documentation, the current version is Version 11 and it's Clipboard documentation is here:

https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/concepts/services/clipboard